# Roland UM4 driver working with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, midi

Is there one? The XP/2000 driver seems incompatible with windows 7. Will it work with Wine?

### Update 130526

It's not working even though I follow the instructions from the answer. 
[image]
[image]

### Update 130526 13:32

I think I got the registry right but it's still not working. There is no way to select compatibility mode for a .inf file on my system and the system just complains when I try to install the 32-bit driver.

[image][image]

Comment: What you've done is something different than @STTR described in his answer. You can see that he has a `Setup` key with a value `DisableDecoratedModelIsRequirement` of type DWORD with `1` in it. You have a `Setup` key with `DisableDecoratedModelIsRequirement` **key** (not value) in it, then another `DWORD` key (DWORD should be value's type) and then `1` value set to `0`.

Comment: Delete the `DisableDecoratedModelIsRequirement` key you've created and open it's parent key (called `Setup`). Right-click it in the left pane and choose *New -> DWORD value*, it will appear in the right pane. Rename it to `DisableDecoratedModelIsRequirement`, double-click it and set to `1`.

Comment: Thank you I think I got the registry right but it's still not working. All I want to do is some simple MIDI sequencing, why must nothing be possible?

Comment: @NickRosencrantz Alternatively, you can copy the files into directories and create a service that runs driver. In general, try).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a 32-bit driver on 64-bit Windows:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup
DisableDecoratedModelsRequirement 1 DWORD
```

[image: DisableDecoratedModelsRequirement registry regedit]

Use Device Manager and select inf file folder:

[image: Inf Files]

Right Click the driver installation file and select Properties/Compatibility Tab. Select the appropriate options in from the list in the following image

Select Windows XP SP3.

[image: Properties/Compatibility Tab]

Click Apply/OK.

Right Click the file and select the Run As Administrator option to install.

Alternative 2:

Save RDIF1004.INF to RDIF1064.INF;

Edit RDIF1064.INF:

Replace %MfgName%=Roland to %MfgName%=Roland,NTamd64 :

```
[Manufacturer]
%MfgName%=Roland,NTamd64
```

Rename [Roland] to [Roland.NTamd64] :

```
[Roland.NTamd64]
```

Comment: Isn't that for testing purposes only, according to MS? How safe is this registry edit, and can it potentially cause problems for other drivers/devices?

Comment: @Karan Of course can cause. But this is the only way to run a 32-bit driver for the 64 bit system. But the missing driver is even less interesting alternative. In some cases it works, sometimes it leads to the collapse of the system. In general, the removal of drivers using a boot CD Windows 7, like a bad version of events)).

Comment: If that's the case then perhaps the OP would be better off using a VM if possible, or dual-booting with XP.

Comment: @Karan Well, we can offer as an option to install Windows 7 x32 and patch the kernel so that the system could see 192Gb of RAM. There is a slight negative in violation of the license agreement, but I think this item is nonsense).

Comment: It's not working even though I follow the instructions from the answer.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz The registry key is not there a little bit. Moreover, in your case it will not help you. You instaliruete driver using wizards. The key is to install the driver from the inf file. you need a `Application Verifier`. Wait instruction.